# Redirect all requests from one server to another

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, redirect, vps

I have two servers, **Server 1 (A Windows Server VPS)** and **Server 2 (A Linux VPS)**.

Both servers are running NodeJS API using **PM2** without anything like apache or nginx or whatever.

What I want is to redirect all requests from **Server 1** to **Server 2** because I want to shut Server 1 down after a while.

**Server 1 address: [www.pharmart.sy](http://www.pharmart.sy)**

**Server 2 address: [www.pharmartco.com](http://www.pharmartco.com)**

I don't want to redirect using the `res.redirect` method because that would break my application.

The application is a Mobile Application that's why I don't want to use the `res.redirect` method, and I have the link to the server hardcoded in the app so I need to upload another version of it in order to change the link to the second server. I also can't make sure that everyone updates the app and that's why I need to redirect all the requests to the second server.

So all the redirection handling should be done on the **Windows** machine.

What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ideas:

**DNS**

Change the DNS for the server 1 domain to point to the server 2 host. So, then all requests to either DNS name will go to server 2. You may have to wait a little while until any local DNS caching effects time out. An advantage of this approach is that while you are waiting for DNS caching effects to expire, everything stays up as requests either go to a working server1 or a working server2. When cached DNS has finally expired, all requests will be going to server2 and you can then take server1 down.

**Your Proxy**

You could replace the current server 1 process with a proxy that points to server 2. So, any requests incoming to server 1 will be proxied over to server 2. Since a change like this probably can't be made instantly, you might have a short amount of downtime for requests coming into server1.

**Hosting Proxy**

If this is running at a hosting provider, then they probably have a proxy service already running that proxies your public DNS IP address to your actual host.  That hosting proxy could be reconfigured to direct requests for server1 to server2 instead.

Comment: I think the best approach would be by using an A record, because I can't afford downtime at all. I will just create an A record an point it to Server 2's IP address right?